# MariaDB Left join not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, mariadb, left-join

So im attempting to get a list of table and any foreign constraints that exist on them for the sake of attempting some automated mariabackup restores in python. im running the following query:

```
SELECT a.TABLE_NAME, b.CONSTRAINT_NAME from information_schema.tables a
LEFT JOIN information_schema.table_constraints b
    ON a.table_name = b.table_name
WHERE a.table_schema = 'world'
    AND b.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```

My "world" test table, has 3 columns on it - Country (No FK's), CountryLanguage (one fk) and City (one FK). With the above query i'd be expecting 3 tables, 2 returning the FK name and 1 null however the return i get is only the 2 tables with the FK's on them.

I'm sure im missing something but cant quite pin it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the left join condition in the ON clause and not in where

```
    select a.TABLE_NAME
        , b.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    from information_schema.tables a
    left join information_schema.table_constraints b
        on a.table_name = b.table_name
            and b.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY';
    where a.table_schema = 'world'
```

If you use a left join table column in where clause this work as an inner join  .. so juts extend the ON condition with the others clause for left  joined  columns